# Spring Cloud Gateway and TokenRelay Filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I’m trying to migrate JHipster from using Zuul to Spring Cloud Gateway. JHipster uses Eureka to look up routes and I believe I’ve configured Spring Cloud Gateway correctly to look up routes and propagate the access token to them. Here’s my config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          route-id-prefix: /services/
      httpclient:
        pool:
          max-connections: 1000
```

The problem I’m experiencing is the access token is not sending an `Authorization` header to the downstream services.

Here's how things were configured with Zuul in my `application.yml`:

```
zuul: # those values must be configured depending on the application specific needs
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie #see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3126
  host:
    max-total-connections: 1000
    max-per-route-connections: 100
  prefix: /services
  semaphore:
    max-semaphores: 500
```

I created a pull request to show what's changed after integrating Spring Cloud Gateway.

https://github.com/mraible/jhipster-reactive-microservices-oauth2/pull/4

Steps to reproduce the issue:

```
git clone -b reactive git@github.com:mraible/jhipster-reactive-microservices-oauth2.git
```

Start JHipster Registry, Keycloak, and the gateway app:

```
cd jhipster-reactive-microservices-oauth2/gateway
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml up -d
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up -d
./mvnw
```

Start MongoDB and the blog app:

```
cd ../blog
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mongodb.yml up -d
./mvnw
```

Navigate to http://localhost:8080 in your browser, log in with `admin/admin`, and try to go to **Entities** > **Blog**. You will get a 403 access denied error. If you look in Chrome Developer Tools at the network traffic, you'll see the access token isn't included in any headers.

Comment: I was able to solve this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114682/65681). I also had to add `.pathMatchers("/services/**").authenticated()` to my security config, which wasn't needed for Zuul. You can see my [commit here](https://github.com/mraible/jhipster-reactive-microservices-oauth2/pull/4/commits/79a09497e6907fafa8bb141b4feb4736ab3afc23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114682/65681).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/services/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/services/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
```

I also had to add `.pathMatchers("/services/**").authenticated()` to my security config, which wasn't needed for Zuul. You can see my [commit here](https://github.com/mraible/jhipster-reactive-microservices-oauth2/pull/4/commits/79a09497e6907fafa8bb141b4feb4736ab3afc23).